# Bad range of polar streamplot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot streamlines in polar coordinates with matplotlib. However, some issues seem to appear on the ranges of the polar plot. Here is one short example to illustrate the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r1 = np.linspace(0.5, 1, 50)
r2 = np.logspace(np.log10(0.5), np.log10(1.), 50)
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 360)
r = r1

tt, rr = np.meshgrid(t, r)
v = 0*rr
u = rr

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='polar')
ax.streamplot(t, r, v, u, density=1., color='k', linewidth=3)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

With `r=r1` (linspace), there is no problem. But with `r=r2`, the radial range of the plot is wrong and varies in [0.5, 0.82] instead of [0.5, 1.].

What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: I guess the problem is rather that the steamlines range between `[3.16, 6.8]` and not between `[10**0.5, 10**1] = [3.16, 10]`, so the lower limit is correct, but the upper limit falls short of expectations. Maybe you should edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in the expression of r2 in the example. It is now changed so that r2 is in [0.5, 1]. The streamplot is still wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot`'s [doc](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot.html?highlight=streamplot#matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot), both `x, y` have to be evenly spaced. So you can interpolate your data using scipy's [interpolants](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) for instance. [griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata) might fit your needs.

[EDIT] This was solved in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25351231/6522112) SO question with interpolation.